# Drupal/Twig/Symfony Routing Returns "null" for base_url

Tags: php, symfony, drupal, routes, drupal-8

I have been researching for almost 2 weeks on for an answer and have finally decided I needed to ask for help. I am quite unfamiliar with PHP/Drupal but has inherited such a project to update and maintain. The project runs on Drupal 8.3.7 and is hosted with IIS 6.2.

For some unknown reason, links in my html.twig files are being returned with a "null" base_url. So for example...

```
<a href="/home"> ... </a>
```

will link to "null/home" ... After a lot of hacking and trying to figure out if I could manually set $base_url (not a best practice, I know, but I just needed to see if it was possible), I found two peculiar behaviors:

A. If in the associated controller I create a variable **$temp_base_url** and hardcode the value "localhost" and attempt to put the following in my html.twig file (where **item.url** = "/home")...

```
<a href="http://{{temp_base_url}}{{item.url}}">http://{{temp_base_url}}{{item.url}}</a>
```

The text between the anchor tag will show up correctly as **http://localhost/home** while the actual link will direct you to **null/home** .

B. On the other hand, if I assigned **$temp_base_url** to equal "http://localhost" and put the following code...

```
<a href="{{temp_base_url}}{{item.url}}">{{temp_base_url}}{{item.url}}</a>
```

The text between the anchor tag will (aga) show up correctly as **http://localhost/home** while the actual link will now try to direct you to **http://localhost/null/home** .

The problem isn't with the global variable **$base_url** because when I test for this within the Controller, $base_url is setting itself correctly to "localhost" so I suspect Symfony or something else rendering the routes incorrectly (any attempts to use 'path' or 'url' has also resulted in similar null issues).

So my question is: Where are these nulls coming from? How do I get IIS/Drupal to pick up the appropriate base url for routing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `url('<front>')`

```
{{ url('<front>') }}{{item.url}}
```